# Add variable into an array in php

Tags: php

I want to add current url inte this code but get error:

Working code without current URL:

```
    <?php
    echo sqr_qrcode(
        vcard,
        array(
            'n' => get_field('name'),
            'org' => get_field('company'),
            'url' => get_field('url'),
            'tel' => get_field('phone'),
            'note' => get_field('current_url'),
            'email' => get_field('email')
        ),
        3,
        false,
        array(
            'fill' => '#000000',
            'size' => '600',
            'background' => '#ffffff'
        )
    );
```

My code that does not work. I want to get the current URL but I think im doing not correct with $link. How do I fix this correct?

```
<?php

$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 
                "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

echo sqr_qrcode(
    vcard,
    array(
        'n' => get_field('name'),
        'org' => get_field('company'),
        'url' => get_field('url'),
        'tel' => get_field('phone'),
        'note' => $link),
        'email' => get_field('email')
    ),
    3,
    false,
    array(
        'fill' => '#000000',
        'size' => '600',
        'background' => '#ffffff'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a misplaced ending parenthesis `)` on the condition,

```
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') ?  "https" : "http" . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got server 406 issues because of using not secure code maby in WP.

I was do like this to get it to work

```
global $wp;

$current_url =  home_url( $wp->request );
```